# Can I go after my employer for false promises? New Jersey

Tags: new-jersey, payment

I work for a wireless retailer and at the time of Black Friday me and my co-workers were told from the 11/22 - 11/25 we would be  receiving commission for the stores sales. For my store it’s only me and someone eles but we sold a total of 99 phones so I would get paid for 99 phone sales and the other guy would get paid for 99 sale
But a week before I would get that paycheck my manager told me
They changed their minds and we were just getting commission for our sales i experience this to my higher ups and got nothing so I’m trying to see if I have a case here?

Comment: What documentation do you have for the commission?  Make sure you have a copy outside company control.

Comment: I do have proof of the of the sales from that time frame the 11/22 - 11/25 and for them telling us about the sale I don’t it in writing but I do have text from my manager stating me having a problem with the Black Friday sale commission and text from my co-workers about the what was stated during the time we were told about commission for the sale

Answer (score 0):

> Can I go after my employer for false promises? New Jersey

Yes, to the extent that the employer is withholding commissions that had been agreed upon. The employer cannot unjustifiably change his mind *after the fact* (the sales). See [here](https://nj.gov/labor/forms_pdfs/lsse/MW-71.pdf) the legislative text of the New Jersey Payment of Wages law.

I am not knowledgeable of N.J. law and court rules, but beware that you might have to do what is known as *exhaustion of administrative remedies* by filing your complaint or grievance with the Commissioner of Labor (or the state Department of Labor) instead of filing a complaint in court.

Additionally, the situation you describe sounds in the torts of *unjust enrichment* (given the sales you made during that period), and *breach of contract*. See [*Vaughan v. Siegel*, No. A-4681-16T2, Sup. Ct. of N.J., Appellate Division (Dec. 24, 2018)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/innjco20181224234):

> A claim for additional wages is a breach of contract claim, which is
>   subject to a six-year statute of limitations. Troise v. Extel
>   Commc'ns, Inc., 345 N.J.Super. 231, 237 (App. Div. 2001); see also
>   N.J.S.A. 2A:14-1.